# Keycloak Federation Configuration, keystore/trustore error when initializing the service

Tags: java, ssl, keycloak, redhat, samba

I'm trying to setup a test enviroment with Keycloak and Samba Active Directory, using the [User Storage Federation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_user-storage-federation) feature from Keycloak to connect to the LDAP database of Samba AD.

Both services are being deployed in containers with Docker, the images I'm using are:

- Keycloak: https://quay.io/repository/keycloak/keycloak
- Samba AD: https://github.com/babim/docker-sambaad

The Samba container generates self-signed certificates in PEM format when starts running, it generates three files called **ca.pem**, **cert.pem** and **key.pem**.

As explained in the documentation here ["Outgoing HTTPS Request Truststore"](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_truststore), Keycloak requieres the setup of a **truststore.jks** file to ensure it is connecting to a trusted server. So following the instructions from the documentation, I generated a **truststore.jks** file using the **ca.pem** and **cert.pem** from the SAMBA container with these commands:

```
$ sudo keytool -import -alias samba-cert -keystore truststore.jks -file cert.pem
$ sudo keytool -import -alias samba-ca -keystore truststore.jks -file ca.pem
```

And then added this configuration in the **standalone-ha.xml** file (the docker image uses by default **standalone-ha.xml** instead of **standalone.xml**)

```
...
<spi name="truststore">
    <provider name="file" enabled="true">
        <properties>
            <property name="file" value="/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/truststore.jks"/>
            <property name="password" value="ExamplePassword1"/>
            <property name="hostname-verification-policy" value="WILDCARD"/>
            <property name="enabled" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </provider>
</spi>
...
```

After this, I use chmod to change the value of **truststore.jks** and **standalone-ha.xml** to 655, just to make sure that the container can read them when it is initializing. Then I use this docker run command to start the container:

```
docker run --name keycloak_app -p 443:8443 \
    -v /srv/data/certs:/etc/x509/https \
    -v /srv/data/sambaCerts/truststore.jks:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/truststore.jks \
    -v /srv/data/standalone-ha.xml:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml \
    -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
    -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=ExamplePassword2 \
    quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:14.0.0
```

But here is the problem, it logs this error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.security.key-store.kcKeyStore: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.security.key-store.kcKeyStore: WFLYELY00004: Unable to start the service.
    at org.wildfly.extension.elytron@15.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.elytron.KeyStoreService.start(KeyStoreService.java:200)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2117)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:243)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.keystore.AtomicLoadKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(AtomicLoadKeyStoreSpi.java:53)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
    at org.wildfly.extension.elytron@15.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.elytron.KeyStoreService.start(KeyStoreService.java:163)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    ... 14 more
```

And this is where I'm really lost right now, I been searching for around a week mainly looking for the "**Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect**" but with no luck.

If I start the container without my modified **standalone-ha.xml** file, it starts perfectly fine and the website is accessible without any problems, but then if I try to setup the [User Storage Federation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_user-storage-federation) without this, Keycloak can find my Samba AD server but it can't authenticate to it, probably because it doesn't see it as a trusted server.

Comment: could you solve this issue? i'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

'keystore password was incorrect' is in your error log. I can see you specified the new truststore via a volume mount, but I don't see you overriding the truststore password. So there is no way of using the new truststore in your container.

See:
[Keycloak Keystore and Truststore setup for docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72459038/keycloak-keystore-and-truststore-setup-for-docker-compose)